# Is there any configuration so that local program on C* node can connect using localhost and remote program using IP/name?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I have two node C* cluster and on these two nodes I want to run spark jobs locally. Inside sparkJob I have to put connection url as localhost so that it will insert data to local C* instance( I am using Cassandra nodes as my spark Job's slaves for execution via Mesos)

Problem is if I change rpc_address=localhost in cassandra.yml then I can connect locally using Spark job(with localhost as connection url) or cqlsh localhost but remote applications cannot connect to node using IP in connection url.

I am using apache-cassandra-2.2.0.

is there any configuration so that local program on C* node can connect using localhost as connection url and remote program's using IP/name in connection url?

Answer (score 0):

I could think of one way this can be achieved is by Extending from RoundRobinPolicy.   (Note: This is for JAVA driver, it could be similar for Spark Cassandra driver)

Override two methods

```
static class NewRoundRobinPolicy extends RoundRobinPolicy{
    distanct(Host){
           return HostDistance.LOCAL;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Host> newQueryPlan(String loggedKeyspace, Statement statement) {
        Iterator<Host> hosts =  super.newQueryPlan(loggedKeyspace, statement);
        final List<Host> hostList = new ArrayList<Host>();
        while(hosts.hasNext()){
            hostList.add(hosts.next());
        }
        return new AbstractIterator<Host>() {



            @Override
            protected Host computeNext() {
                Host host =null;
                for(int i =0; i < hostList.size(); i++){
                    if(hostList.get(i).getAddress().getHostAddress().equals("YOUR IP ADDRESS HERE")){
                        host = hostList.get(i);
                    }
                }
                return host;
            }
        };

    }


}
```

Comment: Actually same spark driver program goes to different slave nodes which have local C* too, I cant put any specific IP in driver program as it might be distributed to different slaves by Mesos. I was looking some setting change on C* side so in code I can simply connect using localhost/127.0.0.1 and other programs which are running outside C* cluster can connect using HOST which you wrote above.